# What is the difference between $f'(x)$ when $f(x) = g(t+x)$ versus when $f(t) = g(t+x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Consider the following two functions:

i) $f(x) = g(t+x)$

ii) $f(t) = g(t+x)$

In the context of finding $f'(x)=\frac{df(x)}{dx}$, I understand that in $i)$ $t$ is a constant.

It is easy to show that in general, if a function $h_1(x)=h_2(x+c)$, where $c$ is a constant, then $h_1'(x)=h_2'(x+c)$.

Therefore, we can apply this result to $i)$ and conclude that $f'(x)=g'(t+x)$, ie $\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\frac{dg(t+x)}{dx}$.

The issue is with $ii)$.

$f$ is a function of $t$, and this is equivalent to a function $g$ of $t+x$, ie $f$ is $g$ shifted to the left by $x$ units.

We can apply the result mentioned above to conclude that $f'(t)=g'(t+x)$, ie $\frac{df(t)}{dt}=\frac{dg(t+x)}{dt}$.

If we now compute $f'(t)$ at $x$ we obtain $f'(x)=g'(2x)$. In the context of computing $f'(t)$, $x$ is a constant.

It seems to me that $f'(x)$ means different things in $i)$ and $ii)$. In $i)$, it is the derivative function of $f$ relative to $x$, evaluated at a generic $x$. In $ii)$, it is the derivative function of $f$ relative to $t$, evaluated at a specific value $x$. Is this interpretation correct?

It looks like I may have answered my own question in that last paragraph.

Comment: The symbol $f'$ has  a meaning only when the variable w.r.t. which you are differentiating is fixed. You are using the symbol $f'$ for both derivative w.r.t $x$ and the derivative w.r.t. $t$. $f'(x)$ has different meanings in i) and ii)

Comment: Is the difference in meaning as I described it correct?

Comment: It is correct. I am suggesting that the symbols $f'$ should not be used in such circumstances. It is better to write $\frac d {dx}$ and $\frac d {dt}$.

Comment: If you are considering $f = f(x, t)$, where $x$ and $t$ are taken as independent variables, I feel that it is better to use partial derivatives and consider ${\partial f \over \partial x}$ and ${\partial f \over \partial t}$.

Comment: "f′(x)  means different things in i) and ii). In i), it is the derivative function of f relative to x, evaluated at a generic x. In ii), it is the derivative function of f relative to t, evaluated at a specific value x. Is this interpretation correct?" I believe, yes.